# Making many bar plots in a one graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a barplot like [this](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/gnxp/files/2011/05/tightness1.png)

I typed:

```
> Japan <- 3137
> China <- 542
> Korea <- 499
> VietNam <- 423
> Indonesia <- 261
> Thailand <- 222
> SriLanka <- 60
> Taiwan <- 56
> Taiwan <- 60
> Bangladesh <- 51
>  Nepal <- 43
> India <- 37
> Mongolia <- 26
> Myanmar <-21
> Philippines <- 16
> Singapore <- 15
> Cambodia <- 11
> Malaysia <- 10
> Pakistan <- 9
>"Lao People's Democratic Republic" <- 7
> "Brunei Darussalam" <- 3
> Afghanistan <- 10
> Iran <- 2
> Yemen <- 2
> United Arab Emirates <- 2
"United Arab Emirates" <- 2
> Lebanon <- 1
> Israel <- 1
> Kenya <- 9
> Botswana <- 7
> Ethiopia <- 3
> Nigeria <- 2
> Mozambique <- 2
>  Uganda <- 2
> Morocco <- 1
> Ghana <- 1
> "South Africa" <- 1
> Zimbabwe <- 1
> America <- 58
> Canada <- 5
> "United Mexican States" <- 5
> Brazil <- 2
> Guyana <- 2
> "Antigua and Barbuda" <- 1
> Cuba <- 1
> Nicaragua <- 1
>  Fiji <- 11
> Australia <- 6
> Tonga <- 6
> Samoa <- 2
> "Papua New Guinea" <- 1
>  Uzbekistan <- 106
> Norway <- 10
> "Kyrgyz Republic" <- 9
> Germany <- 7
> Fracne <- 6
> Tajikistan <- 6
> Austria <- 5
> Italy <- 5
> UK <- 5
> Belgium <- 4
> Denmark <- 4
> Sweden <- 4
> Finland <- 4
> Estonia <- 3
> Lithuania <- 3
> Russia <- 3
> Georgia <- 1
> Netherlands <- 1
> Portuguese <- 1
> Iceland <- 1
> Kazakhstan <- 1
> Moldova <- 1
> Poland <- 1
> Spain <- 1
> "Swiss Confedeartion" <- 1
> Ukraine <- 1
> plot(Japan, Korea...., col=rainbow)
```

But it doesn't not work. How can I make a barplot?

Comment: You would benefit from some beginner texts/resources on R. See, for example, CRAN's [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/), and http://www.statmethods.net/. Also take a look at `?barplot`.

Comment: However, the general gist of what you are after is: `scores <- c(Japan=3137, China=542, Korea=499, VietNam=423, Indonesia=261); barplot(scores, horiz=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to convert your variables in a data.frame:

```
df  <- read.table(header=F, text=" Japan   3137
 China   542
 Korea   499
 VietNam   423
 Indonesia   261
 Thailand   222
 SriLanka   60
 Taiwan   56
 Taiwan   60
 Bangladesh   51
  Nepal   43
 India   37
 Mongolia   26
 Myanmar  21
 Philippines   16
 Singapore   15
 Cambodia   11
 Malaysia   10
 Pakistan   9
 Lao_People_Democratic_Republic   7
 Brunei_Darussalam   3
 Afghanistan   10
 Iran   2
 Yemen   2
 United_Arab_Emirates   2
 Lebanon   1
 Israel   1
 Kenya   9
 Botswana   7
 Ethiopia   3
 Nigeria   2
 Mozambique   2
  Uganda   2
 Morocco   1
 Ghana   1
 South_Africa   1
 Zimbabwe   1
 America   58
 Canada   5
 UnitedMexicanStates   5
 Brazil   2
 Guyana   2
 AntiguaandBarbuda   1
 Cuba   1
 Nicaragua   1
  Fiji   11
 Australia   6
 Tonga   6
 Samoa   2
 PapuaNewGuinea   1
  Uzbekistan   106
 Norway   10
 KyrgyzRepublic   9
 Germany   7
 Fracne   6
 Tajikistan   6
 Austria   5
 Italy   5
 UK   5
 Belgium   4
 Denmark   4
 Sweden   4
 Finland   4
 Estonia   3
 Lithuania   3
 Russia   3
 Georgia   1
 Netherlands   1
 Portuguese   1
 Iceland   1
 Kazakhstan   1
 Moldova   1
 Poland   1
 Spain   1
 SwissConfedeartion   1
 Ukraine   1")
```

Then order it (because I see you want the graph ordered):

```
df <- df[order(df$V2,decreasing=T), ]
```

I would use `ggplot2` to plot this because you have a lot of data and it's better:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df, aes(x=V1,y=V2,fill=V1) ) + #remove fill argument if you don't want colours
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits= df$V1 )  +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate your cooperation.I have an error when I type what you did.Error: unexpected symbol in " ggplot(df, aes(x=V1,y=V2,fill=V1) )geom_bar"     
Error in scale_x_discrete(limits = df$V1) + theme(legend.position = "none") +  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
How can I fix these problems?

Comment: You are welcome! Copy paste my code exactly as you see it. You have forgotten the `+` in the above. It is `ggplot(df, aes(x=V1,y=V2,fill=V1) ) + geom_bar(stat='identity)` not `ggplot(df, aes(x=V1,y=V2,fill=V1) )geom_bar`

Comment: Thank you. I am able to make the graph. I have another question. I want to change V1 and V2 to the names such as the number of people,etc. respectively. How can I do that?

Comment: Check [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_%28ggplot2%29/). You need to add `xlab('name1') + ylab('name2')`

Comment: Thank you. I have to learn a lot.